# Is there a way to get rid of unwanted equipment?

Tags: absolver

As I do in most games, I've been picking up everything that enemies drop. However, after 15 hours in single player and 30+ ranks into PVP, I've accumulated quite a lot of equipment, including a ton of duplicate items that I can't seem to find a way to get rid of.

Is there a way to drop or otherwise get rid of unwanted equipment items? There doesn't seem to be any button to do so, but maybe I'm going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked on several forums as well as [the reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/absolver/comments/6x4535/let_us_get_rid_of_duplicated_gear/). What I can gather from there is that currently you are unable to salvage/destroy items.

> Let us get rid of duplicated gear

[someone else](http://It's%20not%20really%20%22duplicated%20gear%22%20each%20of%20the%20gear%20has%20a%20different%20color%20to%20it.%20Currently%20a%20few%20are%20bugged%20and%20are%20using%20the%20same%20model.) mentioned there might not be duplicate gear at all, some might look the same due to a technical bug

> It's not really "duplicated gear" each of the gear has a different color to it. Currently a few are bugged and are using the same model.